# Merging git repo with submodules to master

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have a microservice type application made up of 10+ microservices. Currently all services exist in one git repo, but this is starting to prove unmanageable because our build/release pipelines are taking a long time to complete because a single change to one of the services triggers the single build for the entire repo.

I'm considering using git submodules to manage this process (so I can create build/release pipelines for each submodule), but unsure of the pull-request process. If I have a repo called Develop with 10 submodules (1 for each microservice) and another repo called master (also with 10 submodules). When I create a pull request from develop to master would I be able to do this once at the parent level (so develop to master), or would I need to create a separate pull request for each submodule that has changes?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a pull request at the parent using this

`git submodule update --recursive --remote`

It will automaticaly pull your submodules, the same way you would do a `git pull` for each.